# OpenVPN config and Network Manager - Key file contains line 'ca ca.crt'

Tags: openvpn, networkmanager

I'm trying to import my OpenVPN configuration to Network Manager via GUI. I am aware that it does not process configurations with inline certificates, so I separated them via script, and CA certificate is located with the config in file `ca.crt`. But when I try to import configuration I get this error: `Error: Key file contains line 'ca ca.crt', which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment`, which is quite bizarre. Are there nuances I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is misleading, as it does not come from the openvpn plugin, but some other VPN plugin. As all plugins fail to import the file, the program does not know which is the best failure message. Try `nmcli connection import type openvpn file "$FILENAME"` to get a better message.

Also, inline certificates should be supported for a while now. And as always, import is just a convenient way to create a connection profile in NetworkManager. You can also click it from scratch (or with nmcli) with the same outcome.